# Generate pdf with reportlab

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

In django project trying to create a pdf using python-reportlab.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

p = canvas.Canvas(response)
p.drawString(10, 800, "Name")
p.drawString(10, 900, "Address")
p.drawString(10, 1000, "School")
p.showPage()
p.save()
```

On output pdf It only shows the `Name`, what happened to other two strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates for "Address" and "School" are simply outside of the page. The origin of the reportlab coordinate system is bottom-left, with the x coordinate going to the right and the y coordinate going up. Try the following instead:

```
p.drawString(10, 800, "Name")
p.drawString(10, 790, "Address")
p.drawString(10, 780, "School")
```

Answer (score 0):

So this works. Just gave smaller values to y co-ordinates. Try playing with these values according to your needs.

```
p = canvas.Canvas(response)
p.drawString(10,750,'Name')
p.drawString(10,650,'Address')
p.drawString(10,550,"School")
p.showPage()
p.save()
```